# Is there any faster way to remove a member from list in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of objects defined as a class like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.v = value
```

My list contains ~ 1e6 of these objects and I remove some of them very often in a while loop like this:

```
from random import randrange

#Number of elements
N = 1000000

# Let's construct the list

Foos_list = []

for i in range(N):
    Foos_list.append(Foo(i))

# Now let's remove members one by one

while len(Foos_list) > 0:
    i_random = randrange(N)
    Foos_list.remove(Foos_list[i_random])
```

I use a random generator to choose which element should be removed in each iteration because in my real case I have somewhat random or sparse access to members of `Foos_list` and I'm not sure if that has any contribution to the slowness that I'm seeing. In fact, the above code works fine up to `N ~ 200000` but after that it becomes so slow. Is there any better way to remove an element from a list of class objects more efficiently in comparison to `remove`?

Comment: One option would be to have a parallel list of boolean values and _mark_ elements as deleted instead of actually deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

`list.remove(list[i])` is redundant, since `list.remove()` needs to search the list for `list[i]` (which is O(n)), but of course, it's at `i`. Use `del` instead.

```
while foos_list:
    i_random = randrange(len(foos_list))
    del foos_list[i_random]
```

Now, `del` is still O(n), so you're not going to see a huge speed boost, but it should help at least -- better than O(2n).

BTW, I made three fixes:

1. Avoid *Upper_snake_case* variable names. Use *snake_case* instead for simple variables.
2. Use `if list` instead of `if len(list) > 0`
3. At some point, `i_random` would be greater than `len(foos_list)` since `N` is greater than `len(foos_list)` after the first iteration.

---

For further speeding it up, we'd need more context. For example maybe you could shuffle the list first, then simply `.pop()` on each iteration, but it depends what you're doing with the list.